# Passing checkbox from popup to child

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to pass the values of the checkbox from a child popup to a parent windows... I can do it with a single value but what I would like to do is to pass multiple values to a textarea: is it possible?

PARENT:

```
<form method=post action='' name=f1>
<textarea name="textbox" cols="10" rows="3"></textarea>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" NAME="Window Name" onClick=window.open("child.php","child","width=550,height=170,left=150,top=200,toolbar=1,status=1,");>Open the child window</a>
```

CHILD:

```
<script langauge="javascript">
function post_value(){
opener.document.f1.textbox.value = document.frm.check.value;
self.close();
}
</script>
<form name="frm" method=post action=''>
<input name="check" type="checkbox" value="test">
<input type=button value='Submit' onclick="post_value();">
```